# I need to check what a ceratin list contains of element in python

Tags: python, list, loops, element

Here I got a bit of my code. What I'm doing here is that for each `n` I'm creating a list of numbers from 0 to 70127. Then the inputs of every existing list (`n.normwind` and so on) would change place according to the index list. After this part have been running how can I for example check whats in the list `n.normwind[index]` for `n=3`? Can this be done?

```
N=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]

for n in N:
    index = np.random.permutation(70128)
    n.normwind=n.normwind[index]
    n.normsolar=n.normsolar[index]
    n.load=n.load[index]
    n.mismatch=n.mismatch[index]
```

Comment: `n` is an integer, it doesn't have a `normwind` property.

Comment: _"the inputs of every existing list (n.normwind and so on)"_  `normwind`, `normsolar`, etc, are not "existing lists".  They are not normal attributes of integers.  The code does not define or create them.

Comment: It's not clear! You're affecting an integer to n.normwind. Unless if normwind is a list of lists with k depth " n.normwind=n.normwind[index]"

Comment: Okay, thanks guys, I do see the problem. Thank You for pointing me in that direction.